# 2 AsyncTasks with a progress dialog in between

Tags: java, android

I have an application where I do some processing on an image and after which I post some text to a database. I currently have this happening using 1 AysncTask. Now what I'm try to do is split the processing and web connection into two AsyncTasks. After the image is processed, I want to display a confirmation dialog to ensure the text it posts is correct(an option to edit it etc). Now I've read that displaying the dialog from within an AsyncTask is bad, so that is the reason to use two.

What I'm asking, is there a correct way to spawn these 2 tasks with a dialog in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I've read that displaying the dialog from within an AsyncTask is
>   bad

`onPostExecute()` can be used to deal with UI elements. Here you can show the dialog. But before showing the dialog you have to check whether the activity /fragment context still exists or not since if the activity/fragment containing `AsyncTask` gets destroyed then you'll get error.

Based on the action taken by the user on your dialog , you can start a new `Asynctask` for your web operation.

Comment: Ok, so if i'm passing the context of the activity to the AsyncTask, a check where or not that reference is null would be ok?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 2):

You can show the confirmation dialog in he onPostExecute() method of your AsyncTask that processes the image, and then from there call a method in your Activity to start the second AsyncTask (or you can also call it straight from the onPostExecute() but that's not very efficient in terms of garbage collection.
Try it and let me know if it works for you.